# Simple database normalization

Tags: database

I have to normalize this database. I'm reading a lot of stuff about how to do it but I can't figure it out. I think it's already in 1NF form but I can't proceed. Can somebody help me?

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZBfD.png)

Comment: You may can separate the company details into a different table and add a foriegn key there. Because the company name can be repeated.

Comment: I moved Company and workedyears to another table together with a foreign key. Is that correct? Is there any further normalization I can perform or that's it?

Comment: The column "workedyears" , is it related to the company or the employee?? if it is related to the employee it should be in the employee table and company related information will be in company table.

Comment: That's my main doubt. It's the amount of time the employee has worked in that particular company, so I guess it's related more to the employee than to the company itself (?). What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it is related to the employee. Consider the same employee worked under another company you will be having info on years worked for that company. You might need 3 different tables here 1. tbl_employee --which contains the all the information of the employee 2. tbl_company -- which holds the information regarding the company. 3. tbl_employee_work -- which has the employee and company related information such as years worked, position, salary etc.